# How do Chrome extension updates install?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have published my chrome extension using the chrome developer portal and then on a test computer installed the extension.

Since then I have uploaded and published an updated version on the developer portal, but it has yet to update on my test computers chrome.

Was there something I needed to program in order for it to update automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens automatically. Wait a day and chrome will upgrade the user's extensions. You don't have control over exactly when that happens.

Comment: Actually, you do have control, i.e. you can force an update: Check "developer mode" and there will be a button "Update extensions" (or something similar).

Comment: No, by "you" I mean the app developer (the guy asking this question) not the user, thou in his particular case he is both. the developer cant force it on the user until chrome decides its time to check for updates. In short the developer has to handle the case of having old versions in the wild

Comment: What you say is true. Still don't forget about **[chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-requestUpdateCheck)**. For testing purposes, there is also the **[--extensions-update-frequency=XX](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html#testing)** switch.